# simple rss feed

Tags: php, xml, rss

i am trying to make a simple rss feed but the problem is when i run the file is says would you like to open rss.php ...

here is the code maybe im doing something wrong? i have put it in this format just to see it work.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8');
?>
&#60;?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?&#62;
<rss version='2.0'>
<channel>
<title>feed title</title>
<description>this is my example</description>
<link>http://localhost:8888/redline</link>
<copyright>Copyright (C) 2010 sarmenhb</copyright>
<item>
<title>Example 1</title>
<description>This is the description of the first example.</description>
<link>http://www.example.com/example1.html</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 29 Dec 2008 22:10:00 -0600</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
<title>Example 1</title>
<description>This is the description of the first example.</description>
<link>http://www.example.com/example1.html</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 29 Dec 2008 22:10:00 -0600</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
<title>Example 1</title>
<description>This is the description of the first example.</description>
<link>http://www.example.com/example1.html</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 29 Dec 2008 22:10:00 -0600</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
<title>Example 1</title>
<description>This is the description of the first example.</description>
<link>http://www.example.com/example1.html</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 29 Dec 2008 22:10:00 -0600</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
<title>Example 1</title>
<description>This is the description of the first example.</description>
<link>http://www.example.com/example1.html</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 29 Dec 2008 22:10:00 -0600</pubDate>
</item>    
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 14):

You should output real `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>`, not an entitized version. Since it's problematic due to php's own `<?`, `echo` it after the header:

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: application/xml');
header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
?>
<rss version='2.0'>
<channel>
<title>feed title</title>
<description>this is my example</description>
<link>http://localhost:8888/redline</link>
<copyright>Copyright (C) 2010 sarmenhb</copyright>
<item>
<title>Example 1</title>
<description>This is the description of the first example.</description>
<link>http://www.example.com/example1.html</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 29 Dec 2008 22:10:00 -0600</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
<title>Example 1</title>
<description>This is the description of the first example.</description>
<link>http://www.example.com/example1.html</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 29 Dec 2008 22:10:00 -0600</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
<title>Example 1</title>
<description>This is the description of the first example.</description>
<link>http://www.example.com/example1.html</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 29 Dec 2008 22:10:00 -0600</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
<title>Example 1</title>
<description>This is the description of the first example.</description>
<link>http://www.example.com/example1.html</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 29 Dec 2008 22:10:00 -0600</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
<title>Example 1</title>
<description>This is the description of the first example.</description>
<link>http://www.example.com/example1.html</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 29 Dec 2008 22:10:00 -0600</pubDate>
</item>    
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: I need to hone my speed-typing skills on this MacBook I just got. +1

Answer (score 3):

Firefox doesn't get the content type in the header: `application/rss+xml`

Though it's the correct one, [formally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595616/what-is-the-correct-mime-type-to-use-for-an-rss-feed), `text/xml` seems to still be a standard with quite a few rss generators and browsers

Try changing the header to

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
```