# how to work with rss file in azure function

Tags: java, azure, rss, azure-functions

I have azure functions with http trigger who get data from external source.
inside the functions I created RSS file with these external data.

I want update this file whenever new data is received (in this state it deletes previous data).

in addition I want to know how I can get the url of this RSS file for used it in logic app.

any idea will be approciated. 
 
  the Function class look like this:

```
public class Function {

private HashMap<String, String> crntNewItemList = new HashMap<>();

@FunctionName("HttpAddFeedItem")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

    // Parse query parameter
    String body = request.getBody().get(); // Get request body

    if (body == null) {
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
    } else {
        String contentType = request.getHeaders().get("content-type");

        initNewsItemList(contentType, body);

        String copyright = "Copyright hold by XXX";
        String title = "Eclipse and Java Information";
        String description = "Eclipse and Java Information";
        String language = "en";
        String link = "httXX://XXw.XXX.com/";
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        Date creationDate = cal.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE', 'dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' 'Z", Locale.US);
        String pubdate = date_format.format(creationDate);
        Feed rssFeeder = new Feed(title, link, description, language,
                copyright, pubdate);

        // now add one example entry
        FeedMessage feed = new FeedMessage();
        feed.setTitle(crntNewItemList.get("title"));
        feed.setDescription(crntNewItemList.get("description"));
        feed.setAuthor("nonsense@somewhere.de (XXX)");
        feed.setGuid("htXXs://XXw.XXX.com/tutorials/RSSFeed/article.html");
        feed.setLink(crntNewItemList.get("link"));
        rssFeeder.getMessages().add(feed);

        // now write the file
        RSSFeedWriter writer = new RSSFeedWriter(rssFeeder, "articles.rss");
        try {
            writer.write();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("success").build();
    }
}
```

****Update****
the RSSFeedWriter class is:

```
public class RSSFeedWriter {

    private String outputFile;
    private Feed rssfeed;

    public RSSFeedWriter(Feed rssfeed, String outputFile) {
        this.rssfeed = rssfeed;
        this.outputFile = outputFile;
    }

    public void write() throws Exception {

        // create a XMLOutputFactory
        XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();

        // create XMLEventWriter
        XMLEventWriter eventWriter = outputFactory
                .createXMLEventWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

        // create a EventFactory

        XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEvent end = eventFactory.createDTD("\n");

        // create and write Start Tag

        StartDocument startDocument = eventFactory.createStartDocument();

        eventWriter.add(startDocument);

        // create open tag
        eventWriter.add(end);

        StartElement rssStart = eventFactory.createStartElement("", "", "rss");
        eventWriter.add(rssStart);
        eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createAttribute("version", "2.0"));
        eventWriter.add(end);

        eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createStartElement("", "", "channel"));
        eventWriter.add(end);

        // Write the different nodes

        createNode(eventWriter, "title", rssfeed.getTitle());

        createNode(eventWriter, "link", rssfeed.getLink());

        createNode(eventWriter, "description", rssfeed.getDescription());

        createNode(eventWriter, "language", rssfeed.getLanguage());

        createNode(eventWriter, "copyright", rssfeed.getCopyright());

        createNode(eventWriter, "pubdate", rssfeed.getPubDate());

        for (FeedMessage entry : rssfeed.getMessages()) {
            eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createStartElement("", "", "item"));
            eventWriter.add(end);
            createNode(eventWriter, "title", entry.getTitle());
            createNode(eventWriter, "description", entry.getDescription());
            createNode(eventWriter, "link", entry.getLink());
            createNode(eventWriter, "author", entry.getAuthor());
            createNode(eventWriter, "guid", entry.getGuid());
            eventWriter.add(end);
            eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createEndElement("", "", "item"));
            eventWriter.add(end);

        }

        eventWriter.add(end);
        eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createEndElement("", "", "channel"));
        eventWriter.add(end);
        eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createEndElement("", "", "rss"));

        eventWriter.add(end);

        eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createEndDocument());

        eventWriter.close();
    }

    private void createNode(XMLEventWriter eventWriter, String name,

                            String value) throws XMLStreamException {
        XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEvent end = eventFactory.createDTD("\n");
        XMLEvent tab = eventFactory.createDTD("\t");
        // create Start node
        StartElement sElement = eventFactory.createStartElement("", "", name);
        eventWriter.add(tab);
        eventWriter.add(sElement);
        // create Content
        Characters characters = eventFactory.createCharacters(value);
        eventWriter.add(characters);
        // create End node
        EndElement eElement = eventFactory.createEndElement("", "", name);
        eventWriter.add(eElement);
        eventWriter.add(end);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please which sdk you use to create RSS file?

Comment: I follow this https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RSSFeed/article.html guide. I update the questions and share also the class how created the rss file.

Comment: @JimXu Sorry for the delay. actually it is not help because the url of file who saved in azure storage can't open in the browser and when I use logic app with rss connector and I put the url of this file nothing happens.

Comment: If you want to use the URL  to access the file in Azure blob directly. You can change the Azure blob access level : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources

Comment: I checked it. in all level I can't open the file directly in the browser. it is must to download. it is not work in logic app.

Comment: Could you please check the content-type of the blob?

Comment: of course. it is `application/octet-stream`. I guess I need edit it to rss type. does I can do it via portal? how?

Comment: Please check my update. We can do that via sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, I suggest you create the rss file and upload the file to Azure blob. In the Azure logic app, we can use the [Azure Blob Storage Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/) to process the rss file.

For more details, please refer to the following steps

1. Install Azure blob storage SDK

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. Update RSSFeedWriter class

```
public class RSSFeedWriter {
    private String outputFile; // the file name
    private Feed rssfeed;
    private String connectionString; // the storage account connection string

    public RSSFeedWriter(Feed rssfeed, String outputFile) {
        this.rssfeed = rssfeed;
        this.outputFile = outputFile;
    }
    public RSSFeedWriter(Feed rssfeed, String outputFile,String connectionString) {
        this.rssfeed = rssfeed;
        this.outputFile = outputFile;
        this.connectionString=connectionString;
    }
    public void write() throws Exception {

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("test");
        CloudBlockBlob blob =container.getBlockBlobReference("test.rss");
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         // create a XMLOutputFactory
        XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();

        // create XMLEventWriter
        XMLEventWriter eventWriter = outputFactory
                .createXMLEventWriter(outputStream);
        // create rss 
        ...

        // upload rss to Azure blob
        blob.upload(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()),outputStream.toByteArray().length);
        outputStream.close();
    }

    private void createNode(XMLEventWriter eventWriter, String name,

                            String value) throws XMLStreamException {
        XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEvent end = eventFactory.createDTD("\n");
        XMLEvent tab = eventFactory.createDTD("\t");
        // create Start node
        StartElement sElement = eventFactory.createStartElement("", "", name);
        eventWriter.add(tab);
        eventWriter.add(sElement);
        // create Content
        Characters characters = eventFactory.createCharacters(value);
        eventWriter.add(characters);
        // create End node
        EndElement eElement = eventFactory.createEndElement("", "", name);
        eventWriter.add(eElement);
        eventWriter.add(end);
    }

}
```

3. update Function code

```
@FunctionName("HttpAddFeedItem")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

 ...

// get the storage account connection string you store in app settings or local.settings.json with the key name
String connectionString = System.getenv("AzureWebJobsStorage"); 
        String outputFile=""; // the file name
        RSSFeedWriter writer = new RSSFeedWriter(rssFeeder, outputFile,connectionString);
        try {
            writer.write();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("success").build();
    }
}
```

---

## update

If you want to directly access the rss file via the blob URL in the browser, please refer to the following steps

1. Please set the container public access level as `Public read access for blobs only`. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources)
2. Please ensure the blob's content type is right. The rss file's content type can be [`application/rss+xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595616/what-is-the-correct-mime-type-to-use-for-an-rss-feed). Regarding how to change the content type, please refer to the following code

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(Constr)
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("test");
        if(!container.exists()){
            container.create();

        }
 CloudBlockBlob blob =container.getBlockBlobReference("test.rss");
 blob.getProperties().setContentType("application/rss+xml");

        blob.uploadProperties();
```

After that, we can access the [file](https://andyprivate.blob.core.windows.net/test/test.rss) in the browser 
[image]
[image]

Comment: I still don't know why but I get error of: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.)` the url is: https://f33e9cb10aaf409fb455.blob.core.windows.net/test/news.rss

Comment: I understand it is related to size of type. in your picture is 640 B. in my case it is empty. do you can tell me how you edit that?

Comment: @YaffaHarari Could you please tell me when you get the error?

Comment: I get it it browser at the console when I enter to the url. (in F12 mode)